# Setting up cakephp3 on azure webapp on linux

Tags: azure, cakephp, azure-web-app-service, cakephp-3.0

I am new to Azure. I would like to setup web app of cakephp 3+ on web app service of azure. I made a web app and tried to install cakephp by composer.
 I get the following error:

> Fixture creation for "requests" failed "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General Error: 5 database is locked"
>   Fixture creation for "panels" failed "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General Error: 5 database is locked"

[image]

I thought this error was the database connection. But I made a custom script and I saw the web server was able to connect to the database server. I also checked for php version compatibility, but it was all fine, as my dev server is running on same php(7.0) with same cake version. I looked into the looked into logs but nothing helped me. When I exported the code/cakephp to other server it works without any issue. Microsoft did not help me.

Please help in solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The "requests" and "panels" tables are used by DebugKit, and created automatically if they don't exist. Presumably, the database user you are connecting to the database with doesn't have "create" permissions here. Either correct that, or disable the DebugKit plugin in your `config/bootstrap.php`.

Comment: It should be noted that DebugKit uses Sqlite by default, so it's often about filesystem permissions. It could also be that the database file is too big, or that it's locked because of concurrent requests, or it's on a NFS which can apparently be problematic, etc, there's lots of possible reasons.